# Is it possible to convert a .net framework webapi2 project to a sdk project style?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Unfortunately I am working a webapi2 .net 461 project and I cannot move to .net core etc...
Can I convert it to sdk style project?

Is this supported? Doing some googling it looks like only classlibrary and console are supported?

Is this still the case?

thanks

Comment: Yes. It appears there are custom SDKs that support Web API 2.  I'm in the middle of trying to get them to work, however. https://github.com/CZEMacLeod/MSBuild.SDK.SystemWeb